# EXE downloaded using cURL does not execute

Tags: windows, curl

I have trying to write a script that install Docker Desktop along with other software. Whenever I download Docker Desktop through cURL, and try to execute the program, Windows Pops Up with `This App Can't Run on This PC`. Running the program that has been downloaded from the website through a browser works fine. The binary size of the two files are exactly the same down to the byte. Compatibility mode doesn't work, either.

Attempting to get the file hashes yielded these results:

```
PS C:\Users\Antonios> Get-FileHash

cmdlet Get-FileHash at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]: C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\windows\dockerDesktop
Path[1]: C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe
Path[2]:

Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          EDF5CB80E3E9AC230FDD1C2BD283D5AE846E659FBF45B3BD3D4233F06B3F497C       C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\D...
```

Comment: Most likely they are *not* the same. When you open a powershell prompt and get the filehashes with `Get-FileHash download1, download2`, are they equal?

Comment: It only shows one hash: ```EDF5CB80E3E9AC230FDD1C2BD283D5AE846E659FBF45B3BD3D4233F06B3F497C```. Is this right?

Comment: No, it should show two hashes. What command did you use? Can you share a screenshot ? *(edit your question and add the screenshot there)*

Comment: I updated the question with code instead. IMO it looks better than a screenshot. The command that you mentioned doesn't seem to work. It gives me the following error: ```Get-FileHash : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Desktop'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-FileHash C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\win ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-FileHash], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Get-FileHash```

Comment: Enclose `C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe` in quotes.

Comment: still one hash using ```Get-FileHash "C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\windows\dockerDesktop", "C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe"```

Comment: What does `Test-Path "C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\windows\dockerDesktop", "C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe"` return?

Comment: True\nTrue. \n for new line

Comment: Weird but ok. Break the `Get-FileHash` up in two commands then. `Get-FileHash "C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\windows\dockerDesktop"` and `Get-FileHash "C:\Users\Antonios\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer.exe"`

Comment: ```Get-FileHash "C:\Users\Antonios\Desktop\github-repos\EZCompile-PHP\windows\dockerDesktop"``` is a blank. That is the file that is downloaded wiht cURL. Does it have no hash? That sounds impossible! You're a wizard harry.

Comment: Every file has a hash. The only thing I can think of is another process having that file exclusively open or you don't have permissions to read the file. Either way, I would have expected Powershell to show you an error.

Comment: me too. All apps are closed that are in the foreground, and all processes running seem nominal. Running as admin still yielded nothing. What is going on?

Comment: At this point, I would download `procmon` from sysinternals, start as admin, add a filter on (part) of the path, try again and examine the output.

Comment: Did I do it right? [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijRNVG41fbqhZfdOfu_xGdaUevDI184j/view?usp=sharing) is a screenshot.

Comment: I can't open the screenshot but you can/should add it to the question.